# Como somar valores dentro de um array?

Tags: c#, array

Tenho um valor inteiro e preciso transformar em um array para fazer a soma de cada um dos elementos individualmente.
fiz da seguinte forma (exemplo):

```
int n = 1230;
string sn = Convert.ToString(n); //converte em string
char[] narr = sn.ToArray(); //converte em array

int t = narr[0] + narr[1]; // realiza a soma e retorna t = 99 (49+50 equivalencia decimal 1 e 2 na tabela ASCII)

Console.WriteLine("\n narr[0] = {0}", narr[0]); // narr[0] = 1
Console.WriteLine("\n narr[1] = {0}", narr[1]); // narr[1] = 2
```

como fazer para somar o valor de cada índice (t = 1+2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar percorrer cada elemento, transformar em numérico, e somar:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string input = "1230a";
    int t = 0;
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        int x;
        if (int.TryParse(c.ToString(),out x))
        {
            t+= x;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n t = {0}", t); // t = 6
}
```

Coloquei um exemplo usando uma string de entrada e não um número, assim pode conter caracteres não numéricos para exemplificar melhor. Usando a sua entrada, ficaria:

```
int n = 1230;
string input = n.ToString();
```

*Update*:

Entendendo que Array é só uma estrutura, a ideia de somar cada elemento dentro implica em percorre-los, mas para as versões >= 3.5 do .net Framework, você pode usar LINQ para isso:

```
using System.Linq;

/*...*/

int y= 0;
int t = input.Select(x=> (int.TryParse(x.ToString(), out y) ? y : 0)).Sum();
Console.WriteLine("\n t = {0}", t); // t = 6
```

Comment: Percorrendo eu consigo realizar a soma, usado estrutura de decisão consigo realizar a soma de parte ou de total do int, mas somar valor de inteiros convertidos em array (usando array) não é possível?

Comment: @AsAlbu atualizei a resposta